# Grails EH Cache object as parameter issues

Tags: grails, ehcache

I want to use EHCache in my grails application. I want to cache a method with @Cacheable.

I am testing this scenario:
Simple test class:

```
class MyTestClassB {
def a
def b

@Override
boolean equals(Object obj) {
    println ("New A" + this.a)
    println ("Olda A" + obj.a)
    if (this.a != obj.a) {
        return false
    }
    return super.equals(obj)
}
}
```

Method to be cached in a service class:

```
@Transactional
class HelpService {
@Cacheable('newcache')
def inlineCacheService(def param) {
    println ("I am in the function")
    MyTestClass a = new MyTestClass()
    a.paramA = new Date()
    a.paramB = [
            id: "1",
            data: "f"
    ]

    return a
}
```

}

So I call the method in the controller:

```
 MyTestClassB c1 = new MyTestClassB()
 c1.a = "paramc1"
 render "1: " + helpService.inlineCacheService(c1).paramA
 c1.a = "paramc1neu"
 render "<br/>1: " + helpService.inlineCacheService(c1).paramA
```

The problem in this scenario is: I changed the value of parameter object, so I expect that I don't get the cached value. But the second call of inlineCacheService reads the value from the cache. What is the problem here? Do I missunderstand something?

Comment: Hmm.. I think this looks ok (although, are you also overriding `hashCode`?). What happens if you put a breakpoint in your equals method and call `inlineCacheService` the second time?

Comment: I didn't override hashCode. That was the problem. Now it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hashCode was missing. After implementation the cache works now as excpected. Thanks to @rcgeorge23